# jquery accordion ui-icon visible on online jquery-ui linking but not on offline jquery-ui download

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, web-applications, accordion

Here is a short description of my problem - >

When I link CSS and Jquery in this way (Offline), then no `ui-icon-plus` appears although everything else including `accordion` and `jquery` is working fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jss/jquery-ui.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-1.8.3.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-ui.js"> 
</script>
```

[image]

But When I do same project by including CSS and Jquery (online) then accordion works perfectly fine along with visible `ui-icon-plus`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"> 
 </script>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or missing something trivial ??

Comment: Looks like you are not loading same CSS file

Comment: Are you sure you're loading exactly the same version?

Comment: I just copied the same file from the links mentioned in second scenarion ... I am 100% sure. Even names are same as you can see.

Comment: Have you put all the files in same folder `jss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've copied the css and js files, but I suspect you may have neglected to copy the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Copy images and put it in /images/ folder.

I think you missed to copy Images or you have done incorrect mapping of images folder.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery-ui-.css file there have been given  an image path in to their server. So if you include that css file in your project,the image path will be wrong. So better to use online jquery-ui.css file.or download icon and change path in css file. It will 100% work.